# Need to upgrade docx-wasm node js

Tags: node.js, ms-word, docx-wasm

I am looking to get into the developer portal for docx-wasm to see my current conversion counts and possible upgrading from the free tier. I cannot get to the site https://developers.nativedocuments.com/

Any help would be appreciated?

Thank you

Comment: Seems like site is still off. Shame, because they seemed to be a really good tool.

Comment: @JasonPlutext Can you provide some information?